# Natural Earth: How to get the position of all provinces that belong to a state

Tags: shapefile, data, geojson, ogr2ogr

This question is about Natural earth [1:10 states and provinces.shp](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-cultural-vectors/10m-admin-1-states-provinces/) file.  I'm using ogr2ogr and want to know the name of the id i need to pass  . In purpose of pulling out the right states regions.

I've use couple  of properties name that didn't work (`-where "adm0_a3 IN ('MLI')" \` , `-where "iso_a2 = 'ML'" \` ). Can anyone help me i'm running out of places to find the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I've just managed to compile the file with ogr2ogr for Germany.

My command was:

```
ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON -where "iso_a2 = 'DE'" provinces.json /path/to/naturalearth/10m_cultural/ne_10m_admin_1_states_provinces_shp.shp
```

I followed Mike Bostocks tutorial *[here](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/map/)*.

I was curious about ML(I). So I chcked it out --- Mali, wow, maybe the file is corrupt according to Mali, because your command should actually be correct I guess.

Cheers, Joehannes